# Extremely slow reports in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have some SSRS reports that are taking a huge amount of time to load (up to 10 minutes). If I run the queries on SQL Server Management Studio, it runs in 40s.

This is happening in production.

So I tried running the same reports locally in Visual Studio (BIDS), and same thing is happening. Query runs fine in Management Studio, but reports are insanely slow.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: are you generating a lot of data? the rendering of SSRS can be slow if you have large reports.

Comment: Check the SSRS logs to see TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing and TimeRendering

Comment: Can you attach your query. You may need some indexing or tuning.

Comment: Hi. Thank you all for your comments. Gelootn, it's not a huge report...average 1300 rows..... Alejandro, thanks for the tip, TimeDataRetrieval was 1057545, TimeProcessing 308, TimeRendering 173....Wes Palmer, the query is running fast on SSMS...so I don't think it's a query issue....Again, thanks guys